# How to stay at pagebottom (with javascript) while loading other page sections above?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I will have a onepager with different sections. I want to start with the last section (bottom of the page)and do load the other sections content with AJAX after the last section has been loaded.

The window does not stay with the last section. After loading the other sections content it follows them up.
How could I stay on the last section as long as I do not start scrolling up?

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: I tryed windows.location, what was obviously wrong, as it reloads

Comment: To clarify your question, are you want to keep the scroll bar at the bottom? while loading contents?

Comment: normally a page starts at the top. So here the conecept is vice versa, the page should start at the bottom.  There will be alot of images and I can'T do lazy loading if I load the whole page first and than scroll automatically down.

Comment: yes, I want to keep the scrollbar at the bottom while loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla Javascript:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

Call this whenever you require to auto-scroll to page bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current scroll position before the data loads and then set it whenever you want..

```
var scrollposition = $(window).scrollTop();

..//Your code

$(window).scrollTop(scrollposition);
```